# Interact with a website by running a script online

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am planning to make a script which basically opens a website. Fills some text in the textarea and then submits the form. The website then redirect. On the redirected page extract the text or data of an element.

I want to run this script through a website and want to be independent of any installations. Because of that I dropped the idea of using JAVA and Python and was using jquery but I can not seem to find how to do it.

I know how to do all the above in JAVA. I used an HTMLwebDriver which is a part of the selinium API.

I want to know that is jquery the best way to do it and how do I do it?

I tried learn some jquery but I can not seem to mix everything together.

I used these commands

```
window.open(url);

$(selector).load(URL,data,callback);

$("button").click(function(){
  $.post(URL,
  {
    name:"Donald Duck",
    city:"Duckburg"
  },
  function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why don't you show us what have you tried to do?

Comment: have you tried selenium?

Comment: I don't think you can with just jquery. You obviously can with selenium, but you might prefer [DalekJS](http://dalekjs.com/).

Comment: I am updating my post by adding what I have tried with jquery.
Also I have tried selinium but I can not depend on java as the user may not have java installed on their computer

Answer (score 0):

Unless you control both domains this is explicitly impossible, as a way of preventing XSS attacks.

If you wish to implement this ability, you will need to create some form of proxy that allows you to do this without running into the XSS protection (as use of a proxy will be the XSS protection)

Comment: But it is totally possible in selinium but not why in jquery?

Comment: @ArchitKhosla Because of the XSS protections that browsers run, only if you control both domains or use a proxy can you get around that protection because you can disable it in those cases.